# How would I re-position my 2nd bg image " url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) " to the right side of page using css?

Tags: css, position, background-image, repeat, background-repeat

```
background-image: url(repeat_bg.png), url(repeat_bg_right_side.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y; "
```

how would I reposition `url(repeat_bg_right_side.png)` to the right side of page ? these are basically 2 small image files i'm using as columns to fill the left and right portion of the bg. thank u for your time [Position of BackgroundImage in Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707562/position-of-backgroundimage-in-windows-form)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
background: url(repeat_bg.png) repeat-y, url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) top right repeat-y;
```

Comment: thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!! how would i add opacity to exclusively " background: url(repeat_bg.png) repeat-y, url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) top right repeat-y; " and not the entire bg ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, you would have to add the opacity to the image in an image editor. The opacity would be applied to the whole div if you were to put in opacity: .8; or something similar.