# How to resize button background image in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I resize button `backgroundImage` in c#?
I could only find properties which gets button `backgroundImage` size. 
Nothing sets size.

I use WinForms

Comment: Which framework do you use? WPF / WinForms / ASP .NET / something else?

Comment: Did you try something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707562/position-of-backgroundimage-in-windows-form)?

Comment: looking for something simpler

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundImageLayout would help...If Not then,
1)Take a Panel (panel1).
2)Bind you Button Event to panel(panel1)
3)Add another panel (panel2) to Panel1 in above with background image that you want to set and BackgroundImageLayout property as ImageLayout.Stretch 
4)Then Resize the panel2
this would resize your image
Hope this helps

Comment: Post is about Winforms

Answer (score 0):

I will not get any simpler than that in WinForms:

```
private void yourbutton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // base.OnPaint(e);     optional
    Rectangle rc = yourButton.ClientRectangle;
    Rectangle ri = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, yourButton.BackgroundImage.Size);
    // e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, rc);  optional
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourButton.BackgroundImage, rc, ri, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(yourButton.Text, yourButton.Font, 
                          SystemBrushes.ControlText, Point.Empty);   // if needed
}
```

If you look at the code you'll see that it effectively really is just one line, or two if you have text on the button..