# Dock Background Image c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im looking to dock a background image to the bottom of a form. Currently I have a background image that is in the centre of the form and would like to change to where the image is at the bottom. 
I have tried docking it but unfortunately failed.

Thanks in advance.

```
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Shooter\Shooter\AppleShooter\Resources\Finalbackground1.png");
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Use a `PictureBox` instead, you can dock that

Comment: I tried picturebox, but Im using a picturebox over a picturebox which doesnt allow for transparency, therefore have to take this method of solution

Comment: I am using c#, Windows form application

Comment: Please try and add the correct tags when posting this kind of question, i.e. [tag:winforms], etc.

Comment: oh ok will keep it in mine!

Comment: Did you try using a Panel? You could dock that at the bottom of your form and set it's background image. 

Edit: I would also suggest adding your image as a resource rather than using Image.FromFile as that will not work if you deploy your application to another PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a transparent background on a PictureBox in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983753/can-i-create-a-transparent-background-on-a-picturebox-in-winforms)

Comment: Not not really. Im not using that method any more.

Comment: No, this is not possible. if you need it you will have to use a helper control, say a Panel. Or draw it in the (On)Paint event. Or create a bitmap of the ratio&size you want at each resize..

Comment: could u expand a little??

Comment: On what? The simplest solution (short of making the bitmap larger at the top) is using a Panel although that may lead to complications in the form layout. But not knowing anything about your form I can't say. I think I would give drawImage in the Paint event a shot..

Comment: You can achieve that by drawing it in the OnPaintBackground() method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707562/position-of-backgroundimage-in-windows-form

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `panel` and dock it to the bottom and then your main `picturebox` you can dock it to the center. In the panel at the bottom add another `picturebox` then dock it to the center, and add the background image. Your form would look like this:

[image]

After you have your selected background image load it in the resource, then add it to the `picturebox`. In the `picturebox` setting be sure to set `backgroundImageLayout` to `stretch` when you maximize the form the background will expand.